# Let $ X = \{a, b, c\}$ and $\mathfrak T = \{X, \emptyset, \{a,b\}, \{a\}\}$ Let $ A = \{a,c\}$

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

Let $ X = \{a, b, c\}$ and $\mathfrak T = \{X, \emptyset, \{a,b\}, \{a\}\}$  Let $ A = \{a,c\}$

I have to find each of the following sets and I think I am on the right track but I know I am not totally correct.

$A'$ which is the boundary of A and I think this is $\{b\}$

I am also supposed to find the closure of $A$ and I think this is $ \{c\}$

However I know the closure of A and $ A \cup A'$ are supposed to be the same and mine are not. Where have I gone wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To see if a point $x$ lies in the closure of a set $A$, you must check that every open set $U$ that contains $x$ also intersects the $A$. The closure is sometimes denoted: $\text{Cl}A$.
Thus, it follow logically that every point in the set is also in the closure, i.e. $A\subseteq\text{Cl}A$. What remains is to check if $b$ is in the closure. There are only 2 open sets that contain $b$, and these are $\{a,b\}$ and $X$. Both sets contain $a$, and therefore intersect $A$. Thus $b\in\text{Cl}A$, and we get $\text{Cl}A=X$. Now, the bondary is what remains when we subtract from $\text{Cl}A$ the maximal open set contained in $A$, which is $\{a\}$. So the boundary is $\text{Cl}A -\{a\}=\{b,c\}$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the closure of $A$ always contains $A$, which is not true of your set $\{c\}$.  Since $A$ is not closed, its closure therefore strictly contains it.

Also, while $b$ is in the boundary of $A$, you should be careful to make sure that no other points lie in the boundary.  For each element $a,b,c$, you need to check whether or not every open set containing that element contains both a point in $A$ and a point not in $A$.  Alternatively, you could compute the interior of $A$ (the largest open set that is a subset of $A$) and then the boundary is the points in $A$'s closure that are not in $A$'s interior.